# Html Form, package C# MVC Core response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I couldn't think of a very good subject but i'll try to keep the description as detailed as possible.

I am asking people a set of questions, each comprising of 5 checkboxes (a likert scale).

The number of questions could be infinite as it is retrieved from a Database.

Each question that a user answers should then return a response, which links the QuestionID with the response value.

The model that is passed to the view is as follows

```
public class PackageResponse
{
    public List<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<Response> Responses { get; set; }
}
public class Response
{
    public long QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int ResponseValue { get; set; }
}
```

The View is as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Likert", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <table id="likert_table">
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var question in Questions)
                        {
                            <tr class="questionRow">
                                <td colspan="7" class="questionCells">@question.QuestionName<input type="hidden" name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].QuestionID" value="@(question.QuestionId)"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="labelCells">Strongly Disagree</td>
                                <td class="inputCells">
                                    <input name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="0">
                                </td>
                                <td class="inputCells">
                                    <input name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="1">
                                </td>
                                <td class="inputCells">
                                    <input name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="2">
                                </td>
                                <td class="inputCells">
                                    <input name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="3">
                                </td>
                                <td class="inputCells">
                                    <input name="Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="4">
                                </td>
                                <td class="labelCells">Strongly Agree</td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="optional">(Optional) Please provide any additional information</label>
                        <textarea id="optional" class="form-control" rows="5" type="text" name="Optional"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" value="Submit">
            }
```

When i submit a completed form, the PackageResponse part of the Controller, returns null:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(string optional, PackageResponse pr)
```

I am unsure why this is happening and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

`Responses` is contained within `PackageResponse` which has a name of `pr` in your Controller, so you will need to change your name to: `pr.Responses[@(question.QuestionId)].ResponseValue`

Second

Make sure your `@(question.QuestionId)` which you use as an index starts at 0 and contains all the values from 0 to n incrementally. If it starts at 1 you will get null.

Also If it starts at 0 and then jumps 1 increment at any point for example `0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6`; your `4, 5, 6` values will not register.

PS

This problem with names can become quite tedious, i'd recommend you invest some time in learning how to us knockout or vue javascript libraries.

Update:

```
@{
     int i = 0;
     for(var a in b) {
        //some stuff here
        <td class="inputCells">
            <input name="pr.Responses[@i].ResponseValue" type="radio" value="0">
        </td>
        //some stuff here
        i++;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anton, the questionID do start from 1 as that is what the Database started the ID's at. What would you recommend instead, or would you recommend a simple questionID - 1 approach?